# Issue retrieving SUM result from query

Tags: php, sql

I have this query here which I use in order to get the sum of a certain column, however I keep getting the error `Undefined index`.

```
$sql_shuma="SELECT SUM(vlera) AS shuma "
          ."FROM   servis_pjeset_perdorura "
          ."WHERE  random = $random";
$resultshuma = odbc_exec($connection, $sql_shuma) or die(odbc_error());

while( $rowshuma = odbc_fetch_array($resultshuma) ) {
    echo $total1 = $rowshuma['shuma'];
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Maybe it's the `$total1` value, I don't know how to save the result.

Thanks

Comment: It seems to be PHP and not SQL issue. I suggest that you add [PHP] tag to your post.

Comment: Do a `print_r($rowshuma)` to see what is in there. According to one user comment on [the odbc_fetch_array() docs](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-array.php), it may not always return an associative array. Keys may be numeric instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is $random an integer? If not, you must use ' ' to delimit the string, like this:

```
$sql_shuma="SELECT SUM(vlera) AS shuma FROM servis_pjeset_perdorura WHERE random = '$random'";
```